# multi dropdown select search form (jQuery,php,mysql)

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax

can anybody please help me, because I'm kinda stuck...

I'm working on a search form (php,MySql) that have multiple dropdown select menus(10) which must be populated from MySql on the fly (like on car sales websites, when you select manufacturer, the second dropdown gets populated, etc...). How can I do this with PHP,MySql,jQuery or AJAX without refresh?

Secound thing is, how can I show results at the bottom of this search page when I select each dropdown value without refresh. For example, when user comes to search page, he sees all products at the bottom, when he narrows the search criteria by dropdown select menues, the results gets more specific.

Thanks for your replies and I hope you understand my question.
BR,
Boyan

Comment: Hi @Boyan, welcome to Stack Overflow. What kinds of things have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi @Hannele, I was currently looking on how to construct database for the automatic populating dropdowns...So far I found these two: [link]http://buffernow.com/2012/08/cascading-dropdown-ajax/  [link]http://www.script-tutorials.com/creating-ajaxy-chained-selects-with-jquery/

Answer (score 1):

First, welcome to the community! You really have to post your code for us to help you out.  Nobody is going to write all of the code for you based off of a scenario.

You pretty much answered your question on how to do it.  Setup a database with your dropdown values, use an AJAX request to a PHP function / file to load the values from the database and return them to your ajax call which then inserts the values into the appropriate fields.

Here are a few links to get you started:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp
http://www.tizag.com/ajaxTutorial/ajax-mysql-database.php
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I'm looking on this tutorial,which I think will be useful  http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp

Answer (score 0):

first off I would suggest displaying automatically the "featured items" or "popular cars"  or have a set that is automatically displayed.  - You do not want to display every result automatically - that is too much and will get slow depending on whats in you db

Then have your first select automatically filled in, you can have an event fire when the user picks something from the dropdown like this

```
$('.myFirstDropdown').change(function() {
     // put ajax here to load second dropdown 
     var firstValue = $(this).val(); // this is the value to pass through ajax
 });
```

you can do this for each dropdown,  then I would suggest a button for the search- this button will do an ajax refresh and display the proper results instead of the featured.  In this `click()` event of the button you will get the value of each select just by `$(.myFirstDropdown').val()` , `$('.mySecondDropdown').val()` ect. to send through ajax

Comment: Hi Scott, can you please give me an example how to do this, because I'm very new to Jquery,ajax,etc... 
How would the working code you wrote look like?
Thx for your help