# how can i amend script to print all elements in a mysql query - php mysql javascript ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

**Multiple Select Dropdown list with Ajax**

Shown below is the text displayed on a web page that has a multiple dropdown select
that connects to a mysql database.
By selecting the dropdowns site, menu and categ the query returns the last column in the table called links which is displayed using ajax on page test.php. **I would like to show all fields in the query?**

Select: site:  menu:  categ:

**actual Result example**

```
coursesweb.net/php-mysql/writing-php-scripts    
coursesweb.net/php-mysql/arrays  
coursesweb.net/php-mysql/php-mysql-using-mysqli
```

**My required result example** Below is the actual output I would like to achieve

site, site, menu, categ

```
coursesweb.net, PHP-MySQL, Lessons, coursesweb.net/php-mysql/writing-php-scripts  
coursesweb.net, PHP-MySQL, Lessons, coursesweb.net/php-mysql/arrays  
coursesweb.net, PHP-MySQL, Lessons, coursesweb.net/php-mysql/php-mysql-using-mysqli
```

**Research**
I have completed all the tutorials in the link below
[multi dropdown select search form (jQuery,php,mysql)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591909/multi-dropdown-select-search-form-jquery-php-mysql)
searched this site and various others this is the 8th revision of my application this version only uses one mysql table as opposed to different tables to create the dropdowns ajax.

**How can I produce the  required result?**

**What I have tried**

I have created a variable called $where_2 in select_list.php which contains the selected values of the drop downs but am not sure how I can append it to the output my best try is to join it to the variable $re_html on the last line of
select_list.php this prints it but not in the format I want. Any help greatly appreciated as a newbie
can you please keep it simple.

**Scripts**

I have included the working scripts below for reference they can  be found at http://coursesweb.net/

```
    // ajax_select.js    

     // Multiple select lists - http://coursesweb.net/ajax/

    // function used to remove the next lists already displayed when it chooses other options
    function removeLists(colid) {
      var z = 0;
      // removes data in elements with the id stored in the "ar_cols" variable
      // starting with the element with the id value passed in colid
      for(var i=1; i<ar_cols.length; i++) {
        if(ar_cols[i]==null) continue;
        if(ar_cols[i]==colid) z = 1;
        if(z==1) document.getElementById(preid+ar_cols[i]).innerHTML = '';
      }
    }

    // create the XMLHttpRequest object, according browser
    function get_XmlHttp() {
      // create the variable that will contain the instance 
          // of the XMLHttpRequest object (initially with null value)
      var xmlHttp = null;
      // for Forefox, IE7+, Opera, Safari
      if(window.XMLHttpRequest) { xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); }
          // IE5 or 6
      else if(window.ActiveXObject) { xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); } 

      return xmlHttp;
    }

    // sends data to a php file, via POST, and displays the received answer
    function ajaxReq(col, wval) {
      removeLists(col);           // removes the already next selects displayed

      // if the value of wval is not '- - -' and '' (the first option)
      if(wval!='- - -' && wval!='') {
        var request =  get_XmlHttp(); // call the function with the XMLHttpRequest instance
        var php_file = 'select_list.php';     // path and name of the php file

        // create pairs index=value with data that must be sent to server
        var  data_send = 'col='+col+'&wval='+wval;

        request.open("POST", php_file, true);           // set the request

        document.getElementById(preid+col).innerHTML = 'Loadding...';   // display a loading notification

        // adds a header to tell the PHP script to recognize the data as is sent via POST
        request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        request.send(data_send);            // calls the send() method with data_send

        // Check request status
        // If the response is received completely, will be added into the tag with id value of "col"
        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (request.readyState==4) {
            document.getElementById(preid+col).innerHTML = request.responseText;
          }
        }
      }
    }


**select_list.php**

     <?php
    // Multiple select lists - http://coursesweb.net/ajax/
    if(!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();

    // Here add your own data for connecting to MySQL database
    $host = 'xxxxxx';
    $user = 'xxxx';
    $passwd = 'xxxxxxx';
    $dbname = 'xxxxxxxx';

    // Here add the name of the table and columns that will be used for select lists, in their order
    // Add null for 'links' if you don`t want to display their data too
    $table = 'sites';
    $ar_cols = array('site', 'menu', 'categ', 'links');

    $preid = 'slo_';        // a prefix used for element's ID, in which Ajax will add <select>
    $col = $ar_cols[0];     // the variable used for the column that wil be selected
    $re_html = '';          // will store the returned html code

    // if there is data sent via POST, with index 'col' and 'wval'
    if(isset($_POST['col']) && isset($_POST['wval'])) {
      // set the $col that will be selected and the value for WHERE (delete tags and external spaces in $_POST)
      $col = trim(strip_tags($_POST['col']));
      $wval = "'".trim(strip_tags($_POST['wval']))."'";
    }

    $key = array_search($col, $ar_cols);            // get the key associated with the value of $col in $ar_cols
    $wcol = $key===0 ? $col : $ar_cols[$key-1];     // gets the column for the WHERE clause
    $_SESSION['ar_cols'][$wcol] = isset($wval) ? $wval : $wcol;    // store in SESSION the column and its value for WHERE

    // gets the next element in $ar_cols (needed in the onchange() function in <select> tag)
    $last_key = count($ar_cols)-1;
    $next_col = $key<$last_key ? $ar_cols[$key+1] : '';

    $conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $passwd, $dbname);     // connect to the MySQL database

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) { exit('Connect failed: '. mysqli_connect_error()); }     // check connection

    // sets an array with data of the WHERE condition (column=value) for SELECT query
    for($i=1; $i<=$key; $i++) {
      $ar_where[] = '`'.$ar_cols[$i-1].'`='.$_SESSION['ar_cols'][$ar_cols[$i-1]];
    }

    // define a string with the WHERE condition, and then the SELECT query
    $where = isset($ar_where) ? ' WHERE '. implode($ar_where, ' AND ') : '';
    $where_2 = isset($ar_where) ? ''. implode($ar_where, ',') : '';
    // DISTINCT  only shows individual elements no duplicates in the drop down
        $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT `$col` FROM `$table`".$where; 



    $result = $conn->query($sql);       // perform the query and store the result
    //print_r($result); // DEBUG
    // if the $result contains at least one row
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
      // sets the "onchange" event, which is added in <select> tag
      $onchg = $next_col!==null ? " onchange=\"ajaxReq('$next_col', this.value);\"" : '';

      // sets the select tag list (and the first <option>), if it's not the last column
      if($col!=$ar_cols[$last_key]) $re_html = $col. ': <select name="'. $col. '"'. $onchg. '><option>- - -</option>';

      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        //printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["site"], $row["menu"]); // DEBUG
        // if its the last column, reurns its data, else, adds data in OPTION tags
        if($col==$ar_cols[$last_key]) $re_html .= '<br/>'. $row[$col]; 
        else $re_html .= '<option value="'. $row[$col]. '">'. $row[$col]. '</option>';

      }

      if($col!=$ar_cols[$last_key]) $re_html .= '</select> ';        // ends the Select list
    }
    else { $re_html = '0 results'; }

    $conn->close();

    // if the selected column, $col, is the first column in $ar_cols
    if($col==$ar_cols[0]) {
      // adds html code with SPAN (or DIV for last item) where Ajax will add the select dropdown lists
      // with ID in each SPAN, according to the columns added in $ar_cols
      for($i=1; $i<count($ar_cols); $i++) {

        if($ar_cols[$i]===null) continue;

        if($i==$last_key) $re_html .= '<div id="'.$preid.$ar_cols[$i]. '"> </div>';
        else $re_html .= '<span id="'.$preid.$ar_cols[$i]. '"></span>'; // $where_2
        //print_r($ar_cols); // DEBUG
        //echo $re_html; // DEBUG
      }

      // adds the columns in JS (used in removeLists() 
          // to remove the next displayed lists when makes other selects)
      $re_html .= '<script type="text/javascript">var ar_cols = '.json_encode($ar_cols).'; var preid = "'. $preid. '";</script>';
    }
    else 
        echo $re_html . ",". $where_2."<br>"; // DEBUG 

    ?>

**test.php**  

    <?php include 'select_list.php'; ?>
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Multiple Select Dropdown list with Ajax</title>
    <script src="ajax_select.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Multiple Select Dropdown list with Ajax</h1><br/>

    <form action="" method="post">
    Select: <?php echo $re_html; ?>
    </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Lovely [SQL injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerabilities...

Comment: I know no its not secure yet but I will work on it once I have sorted this gotcha out, I will use some real_escape code etc. :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks a SQL injection attack waiting to happen:

```
 // define a string with the WHERE condition, and then the SELECT query
$where = isset($ar_where) ? ' WHERE '. implode($ar_where, ' AND ') : '';
$where_2 = isset($ar_where) ? ''. implode($ar_where, ',') : '';
// DISTINCT  only shows individual elements no duplicates in the drop down
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT `$col` FROM `$table`".$where;
```

Use prepared statements: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Once you've fixed that, as far as your formatting question goes, just str_replace() the output.

```
echo str_replace('/',',&nbsp;',$re_html);
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for reply I am just trying your solution :o)

Comment: Awesome, hope it works given your example. There are other options too like preg_replace()

Comment: Many thanks for your reply I have have got the script producing the output I want. concatenating the strings and using string replace earlier in the program did the trick :o) @Zarazthuztra

Comment: @GeorgeThompson remember to accept and upvote working / appropriate answers :)

Comment: @GeorgeThompson don't forget to accept the answer, please mark it so it can be left out of the unanswered ones